# Is it possible to verify attributes of encrypted content?

Tags: encryption, public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs, identity-based-encryption

Let's say that Alice has this information about her,

```
{ "name": "Alice", "age": 25, "eyes": "brown" }
```

which she encrypts with a key pair so that no one access this text.

Later she says Bob that her eyes are brown and Bob should be able to verify only that she has brown eyes, with other information remaining secret.

This mechanism would be similar to merkle tree partial info verification, except we have here the encrypted file not the tree.

Is it possible to partially verify that?

Comment: Are you looking for an interactive protocol (e.g. Alice gives a ZKP that the encrypted record says her eyes are brown), or noninteractive (e.g. Bob, given a guess about Alice's eye color, is able to deduce from the encrypted record whether that guess is correct)?

Comment: My question is about the interactive example

Comment: Perhaps via a form of functional encryption? Still just academic research

Comment: Would a zero-knowledge proof for the statement "I, Alice, know a key that decrypts said ciphertext to a JSON, and said JSON contains `eyes: "brown"`" suffice? Because for that, the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Ruben De Smet yes, it is a good idea. Any suggestions about how to do that?

Comment: Not very interesting maybe, but I don't know what you're doing with the quotation marks in the data about Alice. Sometimes strings get quotation marks, sometimes they don't?

Comment: :) just typos, I will edit